# Why does Valgrind give "Invalid read of size 1" error?

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind

Valgrind is giving me an invalid read error:

```
==37561== Invalid read of size 1
==37561==    at 0x7E81: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:427)
```

for the following code within a class (which I think may be related to a trailing `\0`, but I'm not sure).

```
std::queue<std::string> errorLog;  ///< FIFO used to store errors

const char *Monitor::popErrorFromErrorLog() {
    if (!errorLog.empty()) {
        std::string str = errorLog.front();
        errorLog.pop();
        return str.c_str();
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

void Monitor::reportError(std::string s) {
    std::ostringstream err;
    err << "Error reported: " << s << std::endl;
    errorLog.push(err.str());
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a `c_str`-pointer to a `std::string` that no longer exists: you pop it off the stack and copy its contents to a local variable, then you return the `c_str` pointer of that local variable, which gets destroyed as the function returns.

As for the solution, why not just return `std::string` rather than resorting to C strings?

Comment: Thanks - there had been a need for a method that returned a pointer (which would be null if there was no error), but that's been amended to take a std::string and check for empty().

Answer (score 1):

`std::string str = errorLog.front();` creates a local `std::string`.  When you use `return str.c_str();` you are returning a pointer to the c-string that `std::string` wraps.  Once the return happens the string is destroyed and now you have returned a pointer to memory that has gone out of scope.

I would just return a `std::string` so you do not have to worry about that.  If you cannot do that then you will have to allocate storage dynamically(new{}) and then you will have to remember to clean it up(`delete[]`) when you are done.